# Perl script to Hyperlink to open a file based on the name of the file in each cell

Tags: perl, hyperlink

I had developed a perl script to look for matching strings from text files and copied it into a spread sheet, I had also included the  text file name into the spreadsheet for corresponding matching string. Now I want to hyperlink to open the file by clicking the file name in each cell.

Any help would be much appreciated! I'm not much of a programmer... Thanks!

Comment: What spreadsheet format are you dealing with?

Comment: I am dealing with spreadsheets in openoffice.org on linux machine (CentOS 5.6)

Comment: Which lib you use to write the spreadsheet?

Comment: I use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel module to interface a new Excel workbook

Answer (score 3):

Here is some examples by using the Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

```
# External link to a local file
$worksheet->write('B2', 'external:Italy.xls');

# External link to a local file with worksheet
$worksheet->write('B3', 'external:Italy.xls#Sales!B3');

# External link to a local file with worksheet and alternative string
$worksheet->write('B4', 'external:Italy.xls#Sales!B4', 'Link');

# External link to a local file with worksheet and format
$worksheet->write('B5', 'external:Italy.xls#Sales!B5', $format);

# External link to a remote file, absolute path
$worksheet->write('B6', 'external:c:/Temp/Asia/China.xls');

# External link to a remote file, relative path
$worksheet->write('B7', 'external:../Asia/China.xls');

# External link to a remote file with worksheet
$worksheet->write('B8', 'external:c:/Temp/Asia/China.xls#Sales!B8');

# External link to a remote file with worksheet (with spaces in the name)
$worksheet->write('B9', q{external:c:/Temp/Asia/China.xls#'Product Data'!B9});
```

You can see the [write API](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#write%28%24row,_%24column,_%24token,_%24format%29) for more information.

Comment: Thank you..above examples good to deal with indvidual cells to open a external file. As I will be dealing with 200+ files, I am looking for more auto process. Below is sample spread sheet format..             (ColumnA ColumnB cells are extracted from file name in columnC)         ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC                                                     One       ONE    one.txt                                                 Two       Two    two.txt                                                 and so on...now I want to click on cell one.txt to open the file from the current directory

Comment: Then you need to add a loop, and automatically add those 200+ files into your spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you Jermaine for the help. I am able to open file with examples you had shown above. I am entering the name of the files using script, as already file names are there in one column of spreadsheet I want to  hyperlink all the cells in that particular column. For example in $worksheet->write('B2', 'external:Italy.xls'); instead of 'external:Italy.xls' I want assign dynamic file name to cell

Comment: Do you mean that you need to modify existing excel?

Comment: No..In $worksheet->write('B2', 'external:Italy.xls') instead of (static file name)"Italy.xls" I want open the files whose names are already present in the excel sheet created form perl scipt. In short one of the column has already file names written I want to hyperlink them

Comment: So you want to simply read filenames from the column into a variable X, and modify the column by $worksheet->write('B2', 'external:X'), right?

Comment: Thank you..yes I want to hyperlink all the cells in the column